# tensorflow model not working because of number of epochs

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I have an issue I do not understand. I currently have a model that predicts the winner of NBA games in 2018-19 using the 2013-2018 seasons game as trained data.

My issue is that my model will not train depending on the number of epochs. For some specific epochs it does not train at all.

ex1.[image]

if epochs are 1000 it stays at 0.4137 the entire time

ex2.[image]

100 epochs seems to be fine at the moment but it has given me a static output before

This has happened to me currently with other epochs and static accuracies values. Can someone tell me why my model is being affected by the changing of epoch values? (I made sure that my data was loaded in first. I have also gotten this issue after picking a "good" epoch so I know it is not because I ran before loading in my data. This is not the first time it has happened to me)

github here for my full code : https://github.com/pernutbrian/N.B.A.A.-Never-Broke-Again-Algorithm-

Answer (score 0):

It seems your model has reached a plateau. You can experiment with learning rate to overcome this issue:

```
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2,
                              patience=5, min_lr=0.001)
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, callbacks=[reduce_lr])
```

I see, you didn't use any `sigmoid` activation in the last layer and just taking the linear output. Fix that. Another thing, why use only 6/4/2 units in the FC layers? Try to increase the number of neurons if your model can't learn anymore.

```
...
  layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
```

Comment: I know it may seem like a plateau but that is not the case for my first picture. It was at 0.4137 since the first epoch. My current model plateaus around 70-71 as seen in the second picture.  Should I use softmax instead? I am reading here (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/218542/which-activation-function-for-output-layer#:~:text=sigmoid%20outputs%20produce%20a%20vector,should%20not%20be%20mutually%20exclusive.) that it should be used instead of sigmoid for mutually exclusive events which is what I am dealing with. A team either wins or loses. Thanks for the tips

Comment: For binary classification task with 1 output neuron, you must use `sigmoid`. If you want to use softmax, you need to use 2 neurons.